# R: Trying to count the number of currencies in one data frame based on the positions of the other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames, `X` and `Y`.

```
X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950))

Y <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(3, 16, 180,
                          15, 585, 800 ),
                Stop = c(15, 24, 201,
                         102, 612, 850))
```

I want to obtain  a data.frame `Z` which is a new data.frame with the info of `X` and the counts of `Y` between the range of each "X" row. For example, you can count 3 rows of "Y" which are between the range of the first row of "X" in chr1, so I have a 3 in "Z" in that row.

```
Z <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950),
                Count = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

I would appreciate some help, because until today I have only managed to print the number of rows if "X" dataset has only one row, but I don't know how to achieve my goal. I suppose I have to use some conditional statements plus a for loop to iterate over the rows of "X", but I don't know how to do it.

What I have tried:

1. Tried to calculate the number of rows that match the criteria with only one row in "Y":

   `nrow(Y[Y$Start >= X$Start & Y$Stop <= X$Stop, ])`

Worked when there is only 1 row in "X", but not when I tried to implement it in a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this using the `tidyverse` package.

First I would recommend to choose the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950), stringsAsFactors = F)

Y <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(3, 16, 180,
                          15, 585, 800 ),
                Stop = c(15, 24, 201,
                         102, 612, 850), stringsAsFactors = F)



library(tidyverse)
X %>%
  mutate(count = pmap_int(list(V1, Start, Stop), ~filter(Y, V1 == ..1,  Start >= ..2, Stop <=..3) %>% nrow))

    V1 Start Stop count
1 chr1     0  230     3
2 chr1   540  720     0
3 chr1   920 1270     0
4 chr2     0  350     1
5 chr2   582  635     1
6  ch2   715  950     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that you are a bioinformatician, I would point you to Bioconductor and the `GenomicRanges` package , built specifically for this type of problem.

```
library(GenomicRanges)
X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950))

Y <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "ch2"),
                Start = c(3, 16, 180,
                          15, 585, 800 ),
                Stop = c(15, 24, 201,
                         102, 612, 850))


x <- GRanges(X$V1, ranges = IRanges(X$Start, X$Stop))
y <- GRanges(Y$V1, ranges = IRanges(Y$Start, Y$Stop))

countOverlaps(x, y)
z <- GRanges(x, count = countOverlaps(x, y))
as.data.frame(z)
#  seqnames start  end width strand count
#1     chr1     0  230   231      *     3
#2     chr1   540  720   181      *     0
#3     chr1   920 1270   351      *     0
#4     chr2     0  350   351      *     1
#5     chr2   582  635    54      *     1
#6      ch2   715  950   236      *     1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I was somewhat familiar to the Bioconductor package, but the people of my laboratory don't use it, so I was trying to do it without it. But thanks anyways! I will test your method in the dataset to use it in my own projects, if needed.