# R: Count the number of currencies in one data frame based on another and calculate the mean between the range

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

This post is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559246/r-trying-to-count-the-number-of-currencies-in-one-data-frame-based-on-the-posit) but with a different approach. I have two data frames, X and Y, which I show you here:

```
X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950))

Y <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
                Start = c(3, 16, 180,
                          15, 585, 800 ),
                Stop = c(15, 24, 201,
                         102, 612, 850),
                Dif = c(12, 8, 21,
                        87, 27, 50))
```

I want to obtain Z, which is:

```
Z <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950),
                Count = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                Mean = c(13.66, 0, 0, 87, 27, 50))
```

Which is:

```
V1 = X$V1
Start = X$Start
Stop = X$Stop
```

Count = The number of rows of Y inside the range of the coordinates Start/Stop of X
which I obtain with:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    X %>%
    mutate(Count = pmap_int(list(V1, Start, Stop), ~filter(Y, V1 == ..1,  Start >= ..2, Stop <=..3) %>% nrow))
```

Mean = the mean of the Dif between Y$Start and Y$Stop in the range above mentioned (in the first case it's 12+8+21/3 = 13.66 because this three are the three currencies in Y between the first range of X.

I don't know how to obtain that column, Mean, because when I try a similar approach that I've used with Count column, I don't know how to use mean() without getting an error.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the Mean calculation, please? The dif between Y$Start (3) and Y$Stop (15) for the first row should be only 8 and 12. Why you include 21? Why you and the explanation mentioning the X range too?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have X and I want to map Y into it. So if you see in X, the first coordinates are 0:230 (Start:Stop). In Y, we can see 3 currencies that match this range (3:15, 16:24, 180:201), and the difference between that are 15-3, 24-16, 201-180 (12, 8, 21). So, the mean of this three currencies is 13.66 (12+8+21/3).

So, in the first column of Z we should obtain: (V1 = chr1, Start = 0; Stop = 230; Count = 3; Mean = 13.66).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R's `merge`:

```
# MERGE X AND Y AND CALCULATE Count AND Dif SUBSET
mdf <- within(merge(X, Y, by="V1", suffixes=c("", "_"), sort=FALSE), {    
         Count <- as.integer(Start <= Start_ & Stop_ <= Stop) 
         Dif_sub <- ifelse(Start <= Start_ & Stop_ <= Stop, Dif, NA)
    })

# MERGE (LEFT JOIN) AGGREGATIONS OF Count AND Mean
aggdf <-  merge(aggregate(Count ~ V1 + Start + Stop, mdf, sum),
                aggregate(cbind(Mean=Dif_sub) ~ V1 + Start + Stop, mdf, mean),
                by=c("V1", "Start", "Stop"), all.x=TRUE)
aggdf
#     V1 Start Stop Count     Mean
# 1 chr1     0  230     3 13.66667
# 2 chr1   540  720     0       NA
# 3 chr1   920 1270     0       NA
# 4 chr2     0  350     1 87.00000
# 5 chr2   582  635     1 27.00000
# 6 chr2   715  950     1 50.00000
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/OXED14186)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
require("sqldf")

X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
                Start = c(0, 540, 920, 0, 582, 715 ),
                Stop = c(230, 720, 1270, 350, 635, 950))

Y <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
                Start = c(3, 16, 180,
                          15, 585, 800 ),
                Stop = c(15, 24, 201,
                         102, 612, 850),
                Dif = c(12, 8, 21,
                        87, 27, 50))


Z <- sqldf("select a.*
                  -- ,b.Start as Y_Start
                  -- ,b.Stop as Y_Stop
                  -- ,b.Dif
                  ,sum(case when b.Start is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Count
                  ,avg(coalesce(b.Dif,0)) as Mean
           from X as a
           left join Y as b
           on a.V1 = b.V1
           and a.Start < b.Start
           and a.Stop > b.Stop
           group by a.V1, a.Start, a.Stop
           ")
```

and here's the output:

```
> Z
    V1 Start Stop Count     Mean
1 chr1     0  230     3 13.66667
2 chr1   540  720     0  0.00000
3 chr1   920 1270     0  0.00000
4 chr2     0  350     1 87.00000
5 chr2   582  635     1 27.00000
6 chr2   715  950     1 50.00000
```